# Protractor e2e, chaijs and doSomethingAsync().should.eventually.equal("foo") - TypeError: Cannot read property 'should' of undefined"

Tags: protractor, chai, angularjs-e2e, chai-as-promised, gulp-protractor

It would be helpful to be able to do as chaijs says in their doc: `return doSomethingAsync().should.eventually.equal("foo");`

This would speed up writing my e2e tests as I wouldn't have to explicitly resolve the promises like this:

```
// I wouldn't have to resolve this promise like this as it's very verbose and slows down
// my development 
return somePromise.then(function(resolvedPromise){
  expect(resolvedPromise).to.equal(expectedResult); 
});
```

It would be nice to use chai; chai.expect; chai.should(); chai-as-promise to resolve those promises and assert on them very quickly; however, nothing I have tried worked so far; a search on SO seems to suggest that Chai uses different promise types than Protractor does and that incompatibility in promise type might be resulting in

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'should' of undefined"

This is how I import these libs:

```
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
  chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
  var expect = chai.expect;
  var should = require('chai').should();
  var assert = chai.assert;
```

Has anyone been successful at using `return doSomethingAsync().should.eventually.equal("foo");` without using other libraies like `'Q'`? Again I don't want to rely on other libs like `'Q'`; I just want to use pure chaijs in my protractor e2e if it's possible; NOT the expect() but the `.should.eventually.....`

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you resolve the promise with expect ? `expect(somePromise).to.equal(expectedResult);`

Comment: Because I have to manually resolve the promise.  Basically, I have to put that expect().to.equal() into the callback of the promise, which adds extra code to the tests.  With the .should.eventually..... syntax, I wouldn't have to and my tests would be less verbose